# In TFS Build, how to solve missing project files

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild

I have an existing TFS server (2012) and am transferring a solution from visual source safe.  The solution has about 30 projects and compiles fine locally.

I created a build that is triggered manually.  In each project I set the property group to match the build configuration.

When I build, only some of the projects make it to the source folder and I get errors for the ones that are missing.

Is there anything else I can check?

Comment: It's a bit unclear what exactly your scenario is. Please read [ask], we don't know what your environment looks like. Is it an existing TFS server or a newly installed one? How is the build configured, what triggers it, what file (pattern) does it look for to build? Are you looking in the correct output directory? What exactly do you mean by "the projects are not there"? What property groups are missing from where, and what does the target framework have to do with it? Did you commit and push the project files?

Comment: @Nick Could you please share more information about your issue just as CodeCaster mentioned above?  then we can troubleshoot accordingly for you.

Comment: The issue was the source folder was one level too deep and so the projects one folder up the tree were not being compiled.  I changed the source folder and it started to compile.

Answer (score 1):

In your build definition, go to the **Source Settings** page. Make sure that the **Source Control Folder** is set close enough to the root folder to cover all of the projects needed for the build.